# css button : button horizontal align and size stretch with text size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a button with a left [image], middle [image] (repeating) and right   [image] background:

```
<div class="horizontal">
    <div class="myButton">
        <div class="left" ></div>
        <div class="middle" >
            some text
        </div>
        <div class="right" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css is the following:

```
.horizontal {
      width: 100%;  
}

.myButton {
    width: 120px;
     height: 30px;
}

.left {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5GpP.png");
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 4px;
}

.middle {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXPkE.png");
   /* border: 1px solid yellow;*/
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}

.right {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAPLe.png");
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 4px;
}
```

Now what I need is:

- `myButton` to be aligned in the middle of the `horizontal` block (the page).

[image]

- And the `middle` to be stretched so any text would fit (without manually setting the width to 120px in my example).

[image]

I have no clue how to do this.

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kCBpw/3/ ,

thank you very much.

Comment: take the `width:100px` out of your middle class and add `background-repeat:repeat-x;` for it. Also get rid of `width:120px;` in `.myButton`

Comment: Thank you, how about the problem of aligning the whole thing on the middle of the page?

Comment: simply set a line-height with the same value as your height.

Comment: You should minify your button structure using only 2 containers instead of 3. Merging one side with 'middle' this will reduce images numbers (if you use mouseOver) .. and the html syntax

Comment: But that would repeate the background of the merged side, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stevenschobert/fNdrT/**

To fix the text-wrapping & vertical centering in your `.middle` class, add a `line-height:30px` and a `min-width:50px`;

```
.middle {
    min-width: 50px;
    line-height:30px;
    /* rest of styles ... */
}
```

For the horizontal alignment, you can add a `text-align:center;` to your `.horizontal` class and then a `margin:auto;` to your `.myButton`.

```
.horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.myButton {
    margin:auto auto;
    /* cont... */
}
```

Comment: Woops, sorry I had left that out. I've updated the answer with a new fiddle and explanation :)

Comment: Thanks again. But i there any reason why i dont see the right or left part of the background?

Comment: We cant see it in your fiddle actually.

Comment: Well that's weired it was there at one point (i took my screen shots from jsfiddle). Maybe its because right now i m viewing from my iPhone. I ll recheck once i m on my computer.

Comment: Yeah, the URLs you had in your Fiddle weren't actually pointing the to right images, I've updated my fiddle with the correct URLS and cleaned up the styles a bit. Have another look.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `width` on your `.middle` and `.button` class and set their `display` to `inline-block`. It will take the width of the text!

Comment: thank you for the stretching, how about the horizontal align ?

Comment: Easiest way to align verticaly your text is to use `line-height : 30px;` on your `.middle` class instead of `height : 30px;`

Comment: I Missreaded "horizontal align" to "vertical", but since the button will get the exact width, it will alway be centered. you can add `padding` if you think its too tight.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is you need to take off all the width off of your mid and mybutton. Then once you have done that put a float:left on mybutton and your solution.
!!!Changed my fiddle!!!
http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/kCBpw/6/

.horizontal {

}
   .myButton div {
    display: inline;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
   }
   .myButton {

```
 height: 30px;
```

}

.left {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5GpP.png");
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    height: 30px;
    width: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
   }

.middle {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXPkE.png");
   /* border: 1px solid yellow;*/
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
   }

.right {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAPLe.png");
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/
    height: 30px;
    width: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
   }

Answer (score 1):

You should minify your button structure using only 2 containers instead of 3. Merging one side with 'middle' this will reduce images numbers (if you use mouseOver) .. and the html markups.

HTML

```
<div class="myButton">
    <div class="myButton-inner" >
        some text
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.myButton {
    background: url("../images/btn-left-small-texture.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #9F730C;
}

.myButton-inner {
    background: url("../images/right-big-texture-merging-middle.png") no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
```

This way you're able to manage 'over' effect with just 1 .css declaration and a minor ajustment of your image txture.

```
.myButton:hover,.myButton-inner:hover {
    background-position: 0 fit-for-your-image-px;
}
```

Nota: this is a copy-paste of one of my development, so if you need details, i will comment it for you. But, CSS speaks for itself.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do this, [here's a pure CSS button](http://jsfiddle.net/cQmFB/2/) with this style, just have to adjust the colors to look more like your example:

**HTML**

```
<a class="button" href="">Lorem ipsum dolor.</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid chocolate;
    color: black;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, chocolate 0, beige 1px, beige 3px, chocolate 3px) repeat;
    background-size: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px white;
}

.button:before,
.button:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.button:before {
    left: -5px;
    border-right: 1px solid chocolate;
}

.button:after {
    right: -5px;
    border-left: 1px solid chocolate;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but i'll need lot more complex pictures than this.. doing it using css will be impossible i guess.. thank you anyway and +1 for the effort